# How use or operator in SQL statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

I am new to MySQL. How can I slash and backslash escape? I want to find paths in a table.

```
Path
----------------------
e:\5118\07_Live/Tools\
e:\5118/07_Live\Tools/
```

How can select these two rows using one query? I think it would look like

```
select * from table Path e:(\|/)5118(\|/)07_Live(\|/)Tools(\|/);
```

How should I write my SQL statement?

Comment: You need to use `Path REGEXP '...'`.  Include the `REGEXP`, and it needs to be in a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MySQL recognizes the following escape sequences.
\0  An ASCII NUL (0x00) character.
\'  A single quote (“'”) character.
\"  A double quote (“"”) character.
\b  A backspace character.
\n  A newline (linefeed) character.
\r  A carriage return character.
\t  A tab character.
\Z  ASCII 26 (Control-Z). See note following the table.
\\  A backslash (“\”) character.
\%  A “%” character. See note following the table.
\_  A “_” character. See note following the table.
```

So you need to write your query as

```
select * 
from table 
WHERE Path like  'e:\\5118\\07_Live\\Tools\\' or 
Path like  'e:/5118/07_Live/Tools/';
```

Using regexp to match regex

```
select id, type, details from supportContacts
where type regexp 'e:[\\/]5118[\\/]07_Live[\\/Tools[\\/]';
```

Check this [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/332bb/1)

Comment: The first one won't work, because it only selects path with all `/` or all `\`. The second one is fine though.